# Value in Radio-Group show me only the first word. (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have this JSP file that build me a radio-group with full names of candidate:

```
<h3>Select Candidate from the list: </h3>
    <%
    for(String a: candFullNames.getCand().keySet()){
        %>
    <input  type="radio" name="group1" value=<%=a%>><%=a %>
    <br>
    <%
}
%>
```

in the poll everything looks ok , and I see the full names.
but I want to alert the full name that selected in every change event. so I did this JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(e) {
        alert(this.value);
      });
});
```

and in the alert it's shows only the first name of the candidate. 
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
$(function() {
    $(':radio[name=group1]').change(function(e) {
        var selectedValue = $(':radio[name=group1]:checked').val();
      });
});
```

This is because the `change` event does not fire on the recently checked checkbox, so it's better to *query* the checked one.

**EDIT** Oh, it looks your problem is in the html quotes:

Just add the double quotes to `value` like this:

```
<input  type="radio" name="group1" value="<%=a%>" /><%=a %>
```

Note the added double quotes.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi thanks. I do that but it still gave me only the first name :\

Comment: I edited the answer adding another problem there was

Comment: Welcome :). Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia